# Sum of top 2 numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have three vectors in a function, each of size 2. I want to get the sum of the top 2 numbers at each index. What I mean is this:

```
A = [4,4];
B = [3,5];
C = [5,6];

Sum = [9,11];
```

I would like to skip if-else statements if possible.

Comment: Is the numer of vectors always 3, or is that variable?

Comment: It is always 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to

- concatenate the row vectors into a matrix: `[A; B; C]`
- apply [`maxk`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/maxk.html) along the first dimension: `maxk(..., 2, 1)`, where `2` is the desired number of elements
- then apply [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) along the first dimension: `sum(..., 1`.

Thus:

```
result = sum(maxk([A; B; C], 2, 1), 1);
```

Comment: In general `dim=1` is rowwise with some exceptions for `any` etc?

Comment: Thank you, and lets say my dimensions increase, what do I do then? Let's say now I have vector size 5

Comment: @NikitParakh The code works for any size of the vectors, as long as they are column vectors. If they are not necessarily column vectors, replace `A` by `A(:).'` etc

Comment: @user27286 Using `1` as the dimension argument means work vertically, that is, down each column. I never know if `sum(x,1)` should be called "row-wise" (it does compute the sum of all _rows_) or "column-wise" (it works along each _column_ independently)

Comment: @LuisMendo I am getting confused. `[1,2; 3,4;5,6]` in this case `dim=1` mean it will work separately on `1,2` and `3,4` and `5,6`. And these are one of the rows in  the matrix? Also I was checking the diagram here. Check it once. https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html

Comment: @user27286 Just compare the results of `sum([1,2; 3,4; 5,6], 1)` and `sum([1,2; 3,4; 5,6], 2)`. All other functions that take a dimension number as input, like `any`, `flip` etc, use the same criterion.

Comment: @LuisMendo I guess  I was overhtinking stuff. Btw...that is a lot of reputation right there. Awesome. and thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user27286 Glad I could help! To me the only confusion is in using _names_ like "row-wise" or "column-wise". In my mind, a "row-wise" sum could mean `sum(..., 1)` or `sum(..., 2)`; it's an ambiguous name

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes I get your point. I can understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

First, you concatenate your three vectors through

```
vectors = [A; B; C];
```

Then, you sort it through

```
s = sort(vectors, 'descent');
```

Finally, you sum the two bigger element of each column through

```
SUM = s(1, :) + s(2, :)
```

Comment: What is `vectors.sort`? Are you thinking Python maybe?

Comment: You're right, in Matlab it is `sort(vectors, 'descent')` but it works exactly in the same way.